# Movie where a man runs with a cam in his hand

Tags: identify-this-movie

Guy runs with a cam in his hand while some guys in suits tries to kill man. Eventually the man escapes from these guys but right after that a police car stops at him and a cop kills that guy. 
Things that I remember from the movie

1. American movie around 2000-2010.
2. The guy with camera in his hand is probably an African American Actor.
3. I think the someone will shoot a congressman while he is trying to address a large crowd.
4. There is a guy who wears a black mask.
5. There will be a blast and few of the bad guys enters as firemans and while entering ine of these bad guys will be called to save a random guy who is about die.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [***Vantage Point***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443274/) (2008)

> The attempted assassination of the American President is told and re-told from  various vantage points of different characters. With Dennis Quaid, Matthew Fox, Forest Whitaker, William Hurt, and Sigourney Weaver star in principal roles.