# Action movie which shows the story of a terrorist attack on the US president from different characters' perspectives

Tags: identify-this-movie, action

**Time frame (approx)**

I have watched this movie around 2008-2009, not sure of actual release date though (maybe 2006-2007 rough guess), watched in DVD

**Genre**

Action, Color Movie

**Plot**

This movie basically revolves around a terrorist trying to attack US president and kill when he comes for speech. This terrorist will also have a girlfriend. They show the story from different people perspective, from a terrorist, from a cop and from a guy. (Please note this is the major highlight of the story).

This story also includes a black person, a tourist (please don't take it as racist) who will be always holding camera and trying to record all the events, he also came to listen the speech of president during this time he meets a child with mother, he will be friendly with her.

While he was recording, terrorist shoots the president he also records this one, after actual attack happens cops try to see the accused from his camera. And after attack child and mother goes missing, and he will take care of that child.

At one point during chasing terrorist sees same child crossing the road and child gets scared and stops in front of middle road, at this point again story goes reverse and they show story from another perspective.

**Language**

I have watched in English, it includes hollywood actors I don't know name though.

It's one of the finest movie I have watched which shows same story from different character perspective, and builds story based on that. I forgot name. Can someone please help? I have tried to recall story as much as possible as I have watched it many years back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Movie where a man runs with a cam in his hand](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67030/movie-where-a-man-runs-with-a-cam-in-his-hand)

Comment: One of my favorites since it is one of the few Hollywood movies I watched :P

Comment: Why is this question describing the movie in future tense?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think you're looking for the movie **[Vantage Point](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443274/)** 2008.

A lot of the plot involves different people's perspectives.

**Plot details:**

> The President of the United States is in Salamanca, Spain, about to address the city in a public square. We see a plain-clothes cop, his girlfriend with another man, a mother and child, an American tourist with a video camera, and a Secret Service agent newly returned from medical leave. Shots ring out and the President falls; a few minutes later, we hear a distant explosion, then a bomb goes off in the square. Those minutes are retold, several times, emphasizing different characters' actions. Gradually, we discover who's behind the plot. Is the Secret Service one step ahead, or have the President's adversaries thought of everything?

Here is the trailer:

Comment: Wow!! Awesome! Yes you're right. This is the one I was looking for!

Comment: @VeeraKannadiga - great stuff glad it's the one. If you get a chance please could you mark this as the accepted answer :)

Comment: The movie was great but, as a Spaniard, I felt all the background so non Spanish that it ruined the movie for me (I guess it was filmed in Mexico, I remember seeing a VW Beetle as a taxi cab)

Comment: @Pablo, Besides, why would the POTUS be giving a speech in a public square in Salamanca? O_o I haven't seen the movie, but just that setting is enough for me to break suspension of disbelief.

Comment: Vantage Point, yes. But as a diehard movie buff, I must point out that this is a steal from Rashomon (Kirosawa), and not the only movie to do so.
At the Gate of the Ghost (Thai, 2011), The Outrage (60s), Four Times that Night (1972, Italian) are the biggies. There is a more complete list at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remakes_of_films_by_Akira_Kurosawa), including a lot of "well, kind of like.." movies.